# Scikit-Learn Imputer not Inputting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Imputer with scikit-learn for my project (starting to learn machine learning), and I have scikit-learn installed (and other typical machine learning things), but when I try to input Imputer it tells me that it does not exist. I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and already tried restarting Jupyter Notebook.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

I'm getting this input error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> < ipython-input-1-2e97a66a2985 > in < module >
>
> ----> 1 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer'

Can anyone help? Thank you :)

Comment: I think you're looking for `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Comment: Was trying to use this: http://lijiancheng0614.github.io/scikit-learn/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

Comment: That's from an older version of Scikit-learn. Imputer was renamed to SimpleImputer.

Comment: @MikaO13 that is for the old version of scikit-learn. Check which version you're using.

Comment: How do you check what version you're using? I'm following Hands On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow by Aurelien Geron

Comment: `import sklearn` ; `sklearn.__version__`

Comment: thank you @ImanpalSingh! Also, with Imputer the attribute was imputer.columns to find all of the different values of the imputer, what command is it to find the columns (each data point, since I only have one row and I want to fit these back to a pandas data set) in this (what I got when I used imputer.statistics_): array([-118.51  ,   34.26  ,   29.    , 2119.5   ,  433.    , 1164.    ,
        408.    ,    3.5409])

Comment: I really didn't  understood  your new question in the comment. I suggest search for the question on stackoverflow.com and if you can't  find the answer then post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Imputer` is obsolete I think, it was used in scikit-learn version 0.16.1, which scikit-learn version do you use?

You must have a recent version and therefore you should use this functionality :

```
import sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer
```

You may use other imputers, just check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute).